# Custom infowindow with multiple markers in navigation drawer

Tags: android, google-maps

After all, I've been searching this for hours and nothing could help me...

I want to add a custom info window in multiple markers in Google Map API v2 for Android.

I have this in a navigation drawer, and I've tried a lot of things with null results.

Here is my code:

```
public class ShopLocator extends Fragment {
MapView mapView;
GoogleMap googleMap;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shop_locator, container, false);

    mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);

    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(mapView!=null) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "For a better performance of the shop locator, we recommend to activate the GPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        googleMap = mapView.getMap();

        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        final Location[] mLocation = {null};
        googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

                CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(8);

                if (mLocation[0] == null) {
                    mLocation[0] = location;
                    googleMap.moveCamera(center);
                    googleMap.animateCamera(zoom);
                }

            }
        });

    }

    return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
implements OnMapLongClickListener{

class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter{

    private final View myContentsView;

    MyInfoWindowAdapter(){
        myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        TextView tvTitle = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.title));
        tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
        TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
        tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

        return myContentsView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}

final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
GoogleMap myMap;
TextView tvLocInfo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvLocInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locinfo);

    FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    MapFragment myMapFragment 
        = (MapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();

    myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

    myMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    myMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    myMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

    myMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
    myMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
    myMap.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(true);
    myMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
    //or myMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);

    myMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);

    myMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);

    myMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MyInfoWindowAdapter());

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_legalnotices:
        String LicenseInfo = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(
                getApplicationContext());
        AlertDialog.Builder LicenseDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        LicenseDialog.setTitle("Legal Notices");
        LicenseDialog.setMessage(LicenseInfo);
        LicenseDialog.show();
        return true;    
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

    if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }else{
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices);    
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
    tvLocInfo.setText("New marker added@" + point.toString());

    Marker newMarker = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(point)
                            .snippet(point.toString()));

    newMarker.setTitle(newMarker.getId());

}
```

}

As you can see, the Code for making a Custom Info window is at MyInfoWindowAdapter() method, but before making that, you should have TITLE and SNIPPET, which is located on onMapLongClick() method from the example above.

You must also create a custom XML layout that will be used to make your custom info window..this custom XML layout is the "layout.custom_info_contents" from the code above.

Hope it helps :D